# Connection between $2n$ real fermions and $SO(2n)$

Tags: group-theory, fermions, group-representations, majorana-fermions

In section 11.4 of "[Basic Concepts of String Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642294960)" by Blumenhagen et al, they say:

> Consider a system of $2n$ two-dimensional real fermion (...) transforming as a vector of $SO(2n)$.

I guess they mean that we can take the $2n$-tuple of fermions to be in the fundamental representation of $SO(2n)$. But why do we do this? It seems arbitrary.

I see people saying that fermions transform under $SO(N)$, but I never understood why.